# ALFA not recognising Attributes term

Tags: eclipse, authorization, xtext, xacml, alfa

I downloaded the ALFA plugin for eclipse and followed the instructions in the `alfa-install-plugin.pdf` that was included in the zip archive. It seemed to install OK.

However, when I pasted the example snippet of ALFA into an example file (`test.alfa`), as per the instructions, it failed to "compile" successfully. The `Attributes.subjectId == “alice”` term was underlined in red. This occurs even though the provided `standard-attributes.alfa` and `system.alfa` files are both present in the same `src` directory as `test.alfa`.

I think the plugin should have found the definition of `Attributes.subjectId` in `standard-attributes.alfa` but clearly this did not happen.

Details of my setup:

- ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
- Eclipse version: eclipse-dsl-kepler-SR2 (64-bit)
- ALFA-1.0-update-site.zip (current)
- Oracle java version: 1.8.0_66

Note that alfa was tested on eclipse Kepler (64-bit) on Ubuntu 12.10, which is now at end of life.

I tried several possibilities, but all had the same problem: using the Java developer (not the DSL-specific) version, using different alfa snippets, using a Java eclipse project but not a basic eclipse project, renaming `standard-attributes.alfa` to `Attributes.alfa` (to match its `namespace`), ...

I wonder whether other users have encountered this problem, and if so, how they fixed it!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [ALFA](http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products/authorization-for-applications/developer-tools-and-apis/192-axiomatics-language-for-authorization-alfa.html) Eclipse plugin v 1.0 does not work with the Kepler release of Eclipse. Things changed a lot internally in the plugin architecture of Kepler and hence you will need to use v 1.0.2 of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks @srijith. I was using the version from [the Axiomatics ALFA page](http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products/authorization-for-applications/developer-tools-and-apis/192-axiomatics-language-for-authorization-alfa.html) which downloads as `Axiomatics Language for Authorization Plugin for Eclipse v.1.0.2.zip`. The archive contains `ALFA-1.0-update-site.zip` and that was the version I added recently to eclipse. I've just checked in eclipse using `Help` -> `Check for updates` and there were none. Where would I get the later version?

Comment: @srijith I've just installed ALFA successfully, using eclipse Kepler (SR2) for Java developers and the v1.0.2 ALFA plugin, with Oracle Java 8 on an ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS server. The test ALFA snippet was processed correctly this time, so I have accepted this answer. Thanks!